# Parsing JSON in iOS 5 with AFNetworking

Tags: ios, json, parsing, ios5, afnetworking

I want to parse JSON data received from the Server with the AFNetworking Framework in iOS 5:

```
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
} failure:nil];
```

The JSON data I want to parse looks like this:

```
[ {
    addressReal = "\U6912\U6c5f\U89e3\U653e\U5357\U8def295\U53f7";
    areaTotal = 774;
    balance = 0;
    businessIncome = "556.49";
    equNoString = "";
    equStatusSting = "";
    id = 208;
    staff = 10;

},
    {
    addressReal = "\U53f0\U5dde\U5e02\U5e9c\U5927\U9053668\U53f7";
    areaTotal = 156;
    balance = 6463;
    businessIncome = "174.93";
    equStatusSting = "";
    id = 209;
    staff = 8;

}]
```

How can I now access the JSON?

Comment: I tried to clean up your question and make it actually answerable, but I recommend for future questions that you try to make sure you always state clearly what the problem is that you need help with.  Also see [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) (in particular: *Be precise and informative about your problem*)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use, feel free to fit it to your needs:

```
-(void) loginWithUserID:(NSString*)usrID User:(NSString*)usr Password:(NSString *)psw Sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([sender respondsToSelector:@selector(startLoading)]){
        [sender performSelector:@selector(startLoading)];
    }

    baseURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                  @"http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/test/service.svc/weblogin"];
    NSString* serviceURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                           @"%@?userID=%@&user=%@&password=%@",baseURL,usrID,usr,psw;

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[serviceURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
        self.LoginOK = [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"LoginOK"];
        if (LoginOK.intValue == 1) {
            NSDictionary *usrData = [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"userData"];
            userData = [[UserData alloc]init];
            [userData readFromJSONDictionary:usrData];
            NSLog(@"Userdata: %@",userData);
            if ([sender respondsToSelector:@selector(loginSuccessful:)])
            {
                [sender performSelector:@selector(loginSuccessful:)];
            }
        }else{
            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"No Correct Login Credentials" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [alertView show];
            ;}

    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
        if ([sender respondsToSelector:@selector(stopLoading)]){
            [sender performSelector:@selector(stopLoading)];
        }
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                    message:@"Loginservice not available! Check your connection!"
                                   delegate:nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                          otherButtonTitles: nil] show];
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

    }];

    [operation start];
    };
```

And use a

```
-(void)readFromJSONDictionary:(NSDictionary *)d
{

    [self setProperty1:[d objectForKey:@"property1"]];
}
```

method to get all the properties out of that dictionary into a custom class.

So in your case it would be using

```
NSDictionary *data = [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"data"];
```

Comment: Well, yeah this was an example in case the JSON came in a container called data. If this answer helped you out, and you feel this is the answer to your question, would you please be so kind as to press the checkmark next to it? If it didn't answer your question, or if you need more clarification, don't hesitate to tell!